# PostgreSQL - Count Number of Classes that uses Lecture Theaters

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a set of distinct Lecture Theatres in a University with id (e.g. ABC1) and name (e.g. Theatre A). I want to count the number of distinct classes that uses each Lecture Theatre and rank the Lecture Theatres based on the number of classes *num* (most classes, *rank* 1 etc). Is it clear or do I need to clarify?

```
id   |   name    | num | rank 
-----------------------------
ABC1 | Theatre A | 42  |  1
ABC5 | Theatre E | 37  |  2
ABC7 | Theatre G | 25  |  3
ABC2 | Theatre B | 25  |  4
ABC3 | Theatre C | 10  |  5
ABC4 | Theatre D | 9   |  6
ABC6 | Theatre F | 0   |  7
```

So far I have managed to get the following:

```
id   |   name    
------------------
ABC1 | Theatre A 
ABC2 | Theatre B 
ABC3 | Theatre C 
ABC4 | Theatre D 
ABC5 | Theatre E 
ABC6 | Theatre F 
ABC7 | Theatre G
```

using the following code:

```
create or replace view Lecture_theatres
AS
SELECT distinct r.id, r.name
FROM Rooms r
     JOIN Room_types t ON (r.rtype=t.id)
     FULL JOIN Classes c ON (c.room = r.id)
WHERE
t.description='Lecture Theatre'
GROUP BY
r.id,r.name
;
```

I tried to calculate *num* by adding *count(c.id)* to:

```
SELECT distinct r.id, r.name, count(c.id)
```

However, this seems to return the amount of times a specific class uses any Room, not the specific Lecture Theatre. I'm not sure if I am providing enough information to be able to solve this, but please comment if something is missing!

Comment: Your count has to be on the Lecture Theatre not on the id, add a group by id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not tested and I am not sure if the aggregate inside the window-function does what I think it does. If this does not work, remove the `RANK` function, surround the statement with another `SELECT` (thus using this as subselect) and add the `RANK` to the outer select-list again. This function will give you the same value, if two rooms have the same number of classes.

```sql
SELECT r.id, r.name, COUNT(c.id) AS num, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(c.id) DESC) AS rank
FROM rooms r
INNER JOIN room_types t ON t.id = r.rtype
LEFT JOIN classes c ON c.room = r.id
WHERE t.description='Lecture Theatre'
GROUP BY r.id --if this is a PK, this should be enough; otherwise add r.name as well
ORDER BY num DESC
```

Comment: Just edited the ```RANK``` a little. I tested some similar statement as well, I fell like this should work

Comment: I know this might be a new question so just ignore this comment if It is, but something strange is happening when I LEFT JOIN more tables. For instance LEFT JOIN Courses ON (Courses.id = Classes.course) and then add WHERE Courses.semester = 'S1'. Then, all results with num = 0 disappear. I thought LEFT JOIN would handle this but it doesn't, do you know why Islingre?

Comment: Yes I do. ```LEFT JOIN``` might give you records that have only ```NULL``` entries on the right side (in your case the rooms without a course). Filtering by ```courses.semester = 'S1'``` will therefore be ```NULL = 'S1'``` for these rows and this evaluates to ```NULL```. Thus these rows are getting kicked out and the room does not appear anymore

Comment: Ah I see! Do you know any way of getting around that problem and keeping the NULL entries?

Comment: ```COALESCE(courses.semester = 'S1', TRUE)``` if the field is not nullable. Otherwise you might need to refer to some not nullable field and decide via a ```CASE``` statement in which cases you do not want to "delete" the rows

Comment: LEFT JOIN Courses ON (Courses.id = c.course)
        LEFT JOIN Semesters s  ON (s.id = Courses.semester)
        WHERE
        COALESCE(t.description='Lecture Theatre', TRUE) AND
        COALESCE(s.term = 'S1', TRUE) AND
        COALESCE(s.year = 2011, TRUE)   I tried this and it lets some of the fields that are null pass, but not all of them, am I missing something? Thanks again for the good explanations!

Comment: Cannot find an obvious mistake here.. Perhaps you need to evaluate which rows are kicked... BTW: since ```room_types``` are somehow "mandatory" (there is an ```INNER JOIN```) you do not need to use the ```COALESCE``` there

Comment: I see! Do you have any examples or resources that shows how to evaluate which rows are kicked?

Comment: Well, not really... If feasible, remove the grouping (therefore also your ```num``` and ```rank```; you should add some columns of the other tables to be able to distinguish them) and add the conditions one in each step and check what is happening.

Comment: Really good idea! Now that's really strange. The COALESCE(s.term = 'S1', TRUE) does not affect the null results, but COALESCE(s.year = 2011, TRUE) does. Now I'm really confused.

Comment: This seems suspicious.. But I do not see what happens here.. Perhaps ask a new question and give there your new query and examples of rows that should not be killed and what you found out so far about why they are killed

Comment: I solved it :D Just wanted to tell you how I did. Instead of LEFT JOIN Courses and Semesters I created a View to decide which classes that were valid (S1, 2011) and then I LEFT JOIN:ed Valid classes instead of classes. A bit difficult to explain but thanks a lot. Just wanted to say thank you again!